# Командная разработка сайтов

Tags: php, linux, git, workflow

У нас команда из 5 веб-разработчиков. 
Работаем на ОС Windows (политика компании).

У нас на стеке примерно 15 интернет-магазинов, которые постоянно дорабатываем.
Работа над каждым сайтам ведется следующим образом: у каждого сайта, развернута одна копия (develop), к которой подключаемся по sftp и работаем. Да-да, мы еще динозавтры, работы ведутся не локально и без контроля версий. И часто перекрикиваемся: "Ты сейчас править этот файл?", "Кто добавляли новый метод в классе?" ...

Настало время работать как <s>белые</s> обычные веб-разработчики, т.е.
каждый разворачивает локально копию сайта, ведет работы через гит, делает push на develop там все тестируется и выкладывается на prod.

**Столкнулись с такими сложностями**:

1. Наши пк недостаточно мощные, чтобы запускать даже 2 крупных интернет-магазина. потребуется апгрейд пк всех разработчиков.
2. Работать с сайтами windows нет особого желания, очень привыкли к linux и его архитектуре.

**Возникла следующая мысль**:

А что если, вместе апгрейда наших пк, собрать 1 хороший компьютер (который будет в роли нашего хостинга), создать для каждого разработчика там свою виртуальную среду с linux, где сможет разворачивать свои сайты ?

**Вопросы**:

1. Как думаете, какие есть минусы и плюсы у этого варианта по сравнению с классическим вариантов работы на проектами локально ?
2. Насколько мощный пк нужен, чтобы каждый из 5 разработчиков мог развернуть свои проекты (по 15 средних интернет-магазинов без всяких наворотов). 
   Если кто-то разбирается хорошо в железе, подскажите пожалуйста, какие приблизительно характеристики ПК должны быть (точнее какой процессор)?
   Естественно все эти проекты не будут одновременно работать, максимум 2-3 одновременно, запускать/отключать сайты по мере необходимости.
3. Стоит ли вообще подобным образом работать? или лучше привыкать к windows и работать локально? Почему?

Буду благодарен за развернутый ответ.

Comment: Я не буду голосовать против Вашего вопроса, но на форуме сейчас скажут, что он порождает бесконечные дискуссии, не позволяет дать однозначного ответа и слишком "объёмен" :). Хотя по мне, как не на SO RU делиться опытом разработок. Вы все-такт гляньте на справку "Как задавать вопросы"

Comment: Вы бы хоть зарегистрировались. Этот вопрос вот-вот закроют. Я бы мог возможно немного проконсультировать, только личных сообщений тут нет и ваш вопрос не отвечает требованиям, предъявляемым на этом сайте

Comment: Если вы работаете с windows, то при чем тут вообще дискуссии про линус? Какие такие мощности вам нужны, чтобы запускать сайты локально? Там будет ходить один единственный разработчик, его на телефоне запустить можно будет. Куда больше ресурсов съедят среды  разработки пхп и субд. И какая разница на чем работают сайты? ничего нового при работе локально нет. разрабатывайте на апаче, если политика требует, хостите на IIS. Никаких проблем с этим нет.

Comment: и зачем включать/отключать сайты? если к ним никто не обьращается, то они и ресурсов не используют. да и в любом случае 5 разработчиков не способны создать на сайты какую-либо значимую нагрузку

Comment: Как делали мы: 1 linux машина на VMware. Связка с ldap, чтобы каждый разработчик мог зайти + xrdp. Работает уже как год. Переодически приходят новые разработчики, добавляем мощности на VMware и все.

Comment: У нас докер ген запущен, каждый в свою папку заходит и поднимает свои контейнеры, докер ген автоматически по названию проекта и пользователю создает конфиг, https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen нагрузки почти нет, работают 15 человек

Answer (score 0):

Как я вижу решение вашей проблемы или точнее мой вариант.
Было бы адекватно, собрать не плохой сервер, который может поддерживать сайты, без особых усилий. Для каждого разраба сделать папку на серве в которой будут проекты, а на них настрое nginx или другой сервер.

Каждый разраб выкачает нужные ему проекты ( в которых он работает )( в свою папку). Это требует меньших затрат, чем покупка 15 компов и настройка окружения на каждом.

Вы можете подключаться через puTTy к вашему серверу, и работать через него.

Вы можете так же подключится через PhpStorm к этому локалу.